# How can/could/should I increment a date/time parameter in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter, timestamp, increment

I am sending post requests which have as parameters time and date (among others).

Is there a way in which after sending a request (that fills in an appointment and displays in the UI a Calendar) the time parameter would increase with 30 minutes?

And to cherry on the cake would be that after sending a number of requests for a certain day to be able to change the date and send another bulk of request without copy pasting and manually filling in date and time for each post?

basically today is 07/19/2019, I would have to send out request with time parameter that would be 00:00:00, 00:30:00 and so on. It would total 48 requests.

after sending those the date parameter would change into 07/20/2019 and the time parameter will continue to update the 30 minute mark.

I am not asking for someone to create a script for me (sure that helps), but some guidance because I find it hard to copy paste so many times.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hello, I'm downvoting because I don't see any attempts on solving the problem on your own in your question. Incrementing timestamps is a _very_ usual thing to do with computers, there must be a lot of resources online explaining how to do this. The tags for your question also don't include the programming language you'd like to do this in and there is no code example, so anyone that wants to help you will most likely have to do everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Use [__timeShift](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__timeShift) function with 30 minutes

```
  PT30M
```

Example:

> ```
>  ${__timeShift(dd/MM/yyyy,21/01/2018,P2D,,)}
> ```